# Error While Saving the Image In Core Data

Tags: swift, image, core-data, unrecognized-selector

I get this a runtime error

runtime error:

> Thread 1: "-[Attribute setImageD:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000034aabc0"

when running my code. When assigning the field see * * *

Some background, this started in my project so I striped my code to the minimum but still get this error,

CORE DATA DEFINITION

---

```
extension Attribute {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Attribute> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Attribute>(entityName: "Attribute")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String
@NSManaged public var order: Int32
@NSManaged public var item: Item
@NSManaged public var imageD: Data?
```

}

---

IN THE CALLING CODE I GET THE IMAGE ND CONVERT TO DATA, PASSING IN TO THE SAVING ROUTINE

```
let image = UIImage(named: "BartSimpson");
let imagedata = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
        
= Attribute.createPhotoAttributeFor(item: item,
                                              imageData: imagedata!)

        CoreData.stack.save()
```

---

HERE THE SAVING METHOD GETS A RUNTUME ERROR WHEN TYPING TO SET THE IMAGED FIELD USINNG THE IMAGEDATE... SEE ***

```
class func createPhotoAttributeFor(item: Item, imageData: Data) -> Attribute {
    
    let attribute = Attribute.newAttribute()

    attribute.name = "image"
    attribute.imageD = imageData            // attribute value
```

here  * * runtime error: Thread 1: "-[Attribute setImageD:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000034aabc0"

```
    attribute.order = 3                     // 3 = image
    attribute.item = item                   // parent record

    return attribute
}
```

as requested...  it creates new attribute object, initilises the field (oh but not imageD?) and saves...

class func createAttributeFor(item: Item, name: String, order: Int?) -> Attribute {

```
    let attribute = Attribute.newAttribute()

    attribute.name = name

    attribute.order = Int32(order ?? 0)

    attribute.item = item
    //
    CoreData.stack.save()

    return attribute
}
```

Looking at my own entry here makes me wonder... there seem to be 3 possible error points

Is this the right way to get the data representation of an image?
let image = UIImage(named: "BartSimpson"); let imagedata = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)

is this the right way to pass the data to a function?
= Attribute.createPhotoAttributeFor(item: item,                                                   imageData: imagedata!)

where

class func createPhotoAttributeFor(item: Item, imageData: Data) -> Attribute {

is this the right way to reference the data?
attribute.imageD = imageData            // attribute value

where I error runtime Thread 1: "-[Attribute setImageD:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000034aabc0"

What am I doing wrong?

THANKS
MARK

Comment: Can you post a relevant image  of how your `Attribute` entity is setup in the model editor and in particular `imageD` attribute . I have tried what you have in a new project and it works fine in both Swift & Objective-C.

Comment: What does your `newAttribute()` function do?

Comment: as requested...  class func createAttributeFor(item: Item, name: String, order: Int?) -> Attribute {

         
        let attribute = Attribute.newAttribute()
        attribute.name = name
        attribute.order = Int32(order ?? 0)
        attribute.item = item
        //
        CoreData.stack.save()
        return attribute
    }